# In Jira, is there an issue type for creating an already completed task?

Tags: jira

In Jira, I would like my employees to create an issue that already is complete and closed. The purpose of creating the issue is purely for auditing purposes as an official record that the incident happened and was already taken care of. There is no need to put the issue into "Waiting" or "in Progress" status. If it is going to have a status at all, it should just be "Complete" as soon as it's created. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why is creating it and immediately progressing it through the workflow not sufficient? Alternatively, you can define workflows with any transitions and it's not uncommon to have transitions to the final state. You can use resolutions to differentiate why it's there - such as done versus won't do work.

Comment: Because that’s a lot of unnecessary clicks. You have to create it, then you have to assign it to yourself, then you have to Resolve it, then you have to write out the resolution and then either mark it as Closed or wait until it auto-closes.

Comment: Some of these sound like additional restrictions that you apply. You don't need to assign the issue to yourself to close it. If fields like resolution are required, they would still be required in what you propose. The only argument is that it's a few extra clicks, but if you need to audit work, shouldn't work that gets done immediately be the exception and not the norm? It's effectively shortcircuiting any approval, assignment, and execution processes that you have.

Comment: Maybe you could add a transition to your workflow that would send your issue straight to your "complete" status, and use that transition for those specific issues?

Answer (score 1):

You could create the issue and have a workflow that allow it to change the status into close/done.

You might also want to create some tag or comment for the tracking purpose etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can add your issues to Microsoft Excel or csv file and use importing data from csv feature.

It is well described here [Importing data from CSV on Jira](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/importing-data-from-csv-776636762.html)

And you can set all of them as closed, but you should take the following note into your consideration while setting the value:

> Can only be mapped to existing workflow statuses in Jira. If not specified in your CSV file, imported issues will be given the default (i.e. first) Status as specified in your Jira system.